# The storage account named XXXX does not exist in the current subscription

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to deploy a new Cloud Services package in Azure. However, I am getting the following error from powershell:

> "New-AzureDeployment : BadRequest : The storage account named XXXXX does not exist in the current subscription"

I've used the following script:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "$subscription" | Select-AzureRmSubscription
az account set --subscription "$subscription"
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount –ResourceGroupName "$rm" –StorageAccountName "$storageaccount"

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageaccount -StorageAccountKey "$key"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $target -Container $version -File $source -Context $context -Force
$blobInfo = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $version -blob $target -Context $context
$packageUri = $blobInfo.ICloudBlob.Uri

New-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $cloudservice -Slot Staging -Package $packageUri -Configuration $configPath -Label "$company-$size-$version" -TreatWarningsAsError
```

I've checked and I'm using the right subscription and the URI is correct. We want to centralize all our packages and configuration files for ease of management.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to mix AZ CLI with Powershell scripting, as it is difficult to troubleshoot. Use either Powerhell or AZ CLI.

In you example just change

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "$subscription" | Select-AzureRmSubscription
az account set --subscription "$subscription"
```

to

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "$subscription"
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "$subscription"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/manage-subscriptions-azureps?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Also check if Storage Account name is correct